# Vim regex for matching strings

Tags: regex, vim

How can I create a regex for Vim that accommodates for matching multiple double quotes strings on one line, without matching the text in between the two double quotes strings? A restriction on the pattern is that the double quoted strings can't contain a single quote. So far I came up with `/"\([^']\{-}\)"/` to match the strings below. But as you see it will match the text in between the strings for the second line. I can't rely on white space surrounding the strings, as you see in the third line. And of course it needs to work with the fourth line as well.

- "cat" is called "foo"
- "cat's" name is "foo"
- x="cat's food"
- x = "cat"

Comment: it would be a tricky task for regex, for example `"cat's" name is "foo"` the 2nd `"` (after `'s`) should or should not be matched? the answer is negative, I knew.  because of `cat's`. but `" name is "` is fine... I think you got what I meant.

Comment: I don't quite understand what exactly it is you want to match. Could you add an explanation to your four examples of what parts of the line you want to match?

Comment: Thanks. I would like to match all the double quoted strings in the example, excluding the ones which contain a single quote. So I want "cat", "foo", "foo", "cat" and not "cat's" or "cat's food".

Comment: @kodnin wait, you want to only match the double quotes (`"`) or the double quotes and the string wrapped by them, if the string doesn't contain single quote `'`? you better edit your question, to explain a bit. e.g. `line: xxx, what you want to get is yyyy` use the code block pls.

Comment: @kent, basically I want to retrieve the contents from within the double quotes. This way I can replace them with single quotes. It goes without saying that I do not want to replace double quotes for single quotes when there is a single quote inside.

Comment: @kodnin could the string wrapped by `"` has leading space? like `"     cat dog"`?

Comment: @kent yes, that would be a valid string.

Answer (score 2):

> basically I want to retrieve the contents from within the double
>   quotes. This way I can replace them with single quotes. It goes
>   without saying that I do not want to replace double quotes for single
>   quotes when there is a single quote inside

I didn't find a way to write a simple regex to match your need, but with vim's `:s` there is a way:

```
%s/\v"([^"]*)"/\=stridx(submatch(1),"'")>=0?submatch(0):"'".submatch(1)."'"/g
```

after you executed the above line, your example text would be changed into:

```
'cat' is called 'foo'
"cat's" name is 'foo'
x="cat's food"
x = 'cat'
```

Comment: That looks interesting, appreciate the effort! Still wondering if this line could be refactored into something more simple.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure I understand what you need here, but

```
/\("\([^"]*'[^"]*\)\)\@<!\("\([^"^']*\)"\)
```

matched all the strings from your example that are in double quotes, but not those containing single quotes.

```
"cat" is called "foo"   => "cat", "foo" highlighted
"cat's" name is "foo"   => "foo" highlighted
x="cat's food"          => nothing highlighted
x = "cat"               => "cat" highlighted
```

[highlighted here means: found by the regex search in vim when prompted the command from above]

This uses the `\@<!` construct which is vim-regex syntax for negative look-behind ([see vim manual here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern-multi-items)). Matches double quotes that are not preceded by a quote and a single quote.
This still has trouble if a single quote exists outside of double quotes though. I don't know if thats a problem, let me know if it is.

Comment: I don't want the strings containing the single quote, like "cat's" and "cat's food".